# How does VIM's Ultisnips plugin handle delete inside of HTML snips? How do I change id to class in a div?

Tags: vim, snipmate, ultisnips

I'm new to Ultisnips.  In insert mode I type div [tab] then I get:

```
<div id="name">

</div>
```

With the cursor on name. If i wan't to use class instead of id I hit backspace and get this

```
<div>

</div>
```

With the cursor on the first v. Now if I want to start typing 'class' I end up with this

```
<diclassv>

</div>
```

If I delete class and hit [esc] l i 'class' I end up with this

```
<div id=" "class>

</div>
```

What's going on here? What am I doing wrong?

I want

```
<div class="foo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not finding a way to do what you're looking for either, at least with the 
standard snippet definitions.

I've created an improved snippet for that which you can start using by placing 
the following in `~/.vim/UltiSnips/html.snippets` (my version of that file is available from 
[GitHub](https://raw.github.com/aschrab/dotfiles/046317e4fdeca30e6f4b97386b915690c639746e/vim/UltiSnips/html.snippets)):

```
clearsnippets div
snippet div "XHTML <div>"
<div`!p snip.rv=' id="' if t[1] else ""`${1:name}`!p snip.rv = '"' if t[1] else ""``!p snip.rv=' class="' if t[2] else ""`${2:name}`!p snip.rv = '"' if t[2] else ""`>
   $0
</div>
endsnippet
```

This will provide both `id` and `class` attributes by default, eliminating the 
one(s) where the value is deleted.

The [official version](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) of UltiSnips on GitHub now includes this version of the snippet.

Comment: This works great just grabbed it from the package on github, thanks!

Comment: In the new version, you have div (regular div) div. (div class) and div#